# Find the number of elements greater than a number in a list in PROLOG

Tags: prolog

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read this question. I have the following problem:

Given a list that returned the number of numbers greater than X Example:

greater (4, [1,2,3,4,5,6], N) Result. N = 2
My code is:

```
greater(0,[],0):-!, fail.
greater(N,[N],1).
greater(N,[H|Q],X):-H>N,greater(Q,N,X),X is X+1.
```

The problem is that PROLOG only returns **False** but not the value of **X**.

I hope you can explain to me what I am doing wrong, I thank you in advance for your

Comment: `X is X+1` is *non-sensical*. A variable can only be unified with one value, and a variable thus can not be `1` and `2` at the same time.

Comment: Why do you write `fail` in the first clause? Furthermor what should happen if `H <= N` here?

Comment: I write fail in case the list is empty.

Comment: then I do not use the same variable I can use an auxiliary variable.

Comment: i´m very sorry, it has  to be recursive.

Comment: Since the absence of a successful query is failure in Prolog, you don't need `greater(0,[],0):-!, fail.`. `greater(0, [], 0)` will fail if it doesn't succeed via your other predicate clauses. Your base case, `greater(N,[N],1).` is not correct. This says that `N` is greater than `N`, which certainly isn't true. What should the base case be? What is the case where you have a single element list and a number? When should it succeed with 1?

Comment: You'll also need a `greater(N,[H|Q],X) :-...` a success case in which it is not true that `H > N` so that the predicate continues. Otherwise, that case will fail and the whole predicate fails. William hinted at this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a predicate call fails in Prolog if there are no success paths for that call, then the following predicate clause serves no purpose. You can remove it.

```
greater(0,[],0):-!, fail.
```

Your next clause is your recursive base case and is incorrectly formulated:

```
greater(N,[N],1).
```

This succeeds even though it violates your condition that you want to count elements in the list that are *greater* than `N`. `N` is not greater than `N`. What should this clause look like if you want `greater(N, [X], 1).` to succeed?

In your recursive clause, you have a problem:

```
greater(N,[H|Q],X):-H>N,greater(Q,N,X),X is X+1.
```

`X is X+1` will *always* fail because the value of `X` cannot possibly ever be the same as the value `X+1`. That is, there is no number that is equal to itself plus one. You need to use an auxiliary variable:

```
greater(N,[H|Q],X):-H>N,greater(Q,N,X1),X is X1+1.
```

Finally, you're missing the case when `H =< N`:

```
greater(N,[H|Q],X):-H=<N, ....
```

What should this clause look like?

Comment: @Krasnax I'm glad it helped. If you find this answer acceptable, then if you could be so kind as to click the accept button, I'd be much obliged.

Comment: Sure. In the end  I solved it .                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                          
   `greater(_,[],0).% default is 0 
    greater(N,[H|Q],X):- H>N, greater(N,Q,X1), X is X1+1.                              
    greater(N,[H|Q],X):- H=< N, greater(N,Q,X).`